# Call method only once for EACH object of the class NOT STATIC

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, static

I wrote a class where the constructor is private.

I need to assign the given value to the private members ONLY ONCE

in the method `construct(int a)`.

It should be something like a constructor but not a constructor !

Every time this `construct(int a)` is called after the first time, 
I do not need to reassign anything to that specific OBJECT.

How to achieve that without any booleans?

I thought of `boost::call_once` but it calls  `construct(int a)` once for ENTIRE CLASS! and I need to call this function **ONCE for EACH OBJECT**.

just like ctor! Any ideas?

UPDATE 1:
The Constructor is private. But the class has some members those values can be assigned from the outside but only ONCE

I am trying to achieve some automatisation for checking if a function was called or not already without using `bool wasCalled` or something like that.

UPDATE 2:

```
LT::Pointer lut = LT::New();
    std::vector<double> points;
....
    lut->construct(points);
```

The second time

`lut->construct(points);`

is called - error should be given, or just somehow make it impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What's wrong with initializing the member in a constructor and then simply not changing it anymore?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? It is not fully clear from your explanation. Maybe if you provide more background we will be able to give you ideas. From what I understand, a Singleton (or variation) could be useful...

Comment: This is what the ctor is there for. Use a `const` field.

Comment: The Constructor is private. But the class has some members those values can be assigned from the outside but only ONCE

Comment: if the constructor is private, where / how are these objects being created?

Comment: itk library, though New() operation. somehow like singleton but not exactly. I do not understand entirely how.

Comment: The more I read this, the more confused I get.  Could you post some code showing what you have and comments on what you hope to achieve.  I think some context would go a long way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Direct Answer**:

You can devise a wrapper that applies "assign-once" semantics to the wrapped object.

However, you can **not** make the compiler detect that a value is being set for the second  time at compile time, so you should be prepared to make it assert/throw at runtime.

**Background/look around**

As others have said, this smells very much like a design flaw. Why can't you have the `New` operation forward constructor parameters (a-la `make_shared`, `make_unique`?):

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
    SmartPointer<T> genericNew(Args&&... args) {
         return SmartPointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
```

Of course, there could be specialized factory methods that even know how to set private properties after construction. Make the factory methods friends, to preven others from using the hidden property (setters) after creation by the factory:

```
struct X { 
     int a; 
     X(int i) : a(i) {}

     typedef SmartPointer<X> Ptr;

     static Ptr New(int a, int init_only) {
         Ptr p(new X(a));             
         p->init_only = init_only;
         return p;
     }

   private:
     int init_only;
};
```

*(here I opted to make the `New` factory method a static member, so it's implicitly a friend)*

Comment: I fixed a missing return in the second sample

Comment: `Ptr p(new X(a));` <-- would `p` be set to different newly allocated memory each time, right?

Comment: @Oleksandra in my example, yes. But the implementation of `New` is not the point (you didn't show it either)

Comment: That is actually one of the design solutions I was trying to achieve.